# Question about displaying text in LibGDX using a console

Tags: java, libgdx

I had a quick question.  I am writing a text based game using Java and LibGDX.  I want to create something like a console.  I would like to store all previous messages while being able to add new ones.  However, I don't need users to input any data into the console.  I saw that labels might work, but I am unsure of how to keep the existing text while adding new text to a label.  I am fairly new to using LibGDX and thought someone could think of a better way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick suggestion for where to start, since I haven't done this myself:

Label is the typical way to draw text, but it re-computes the glyphs for all the text every time you change the text. Under the hood, it uses BitmapFontCache for the rendering. BitmapFontCache lets you append text using `addText()` without recomputing what it has already done.

So what I would do is use BitmapFontCache directly for your text rendering, and append text to it. Maybe calculate how many lines of text it takes to fill the screen or half the screen, and create a new instance each time you reach that threshold. That way, you can selectively render only the ones that overlap the camera viewport so you aren't drawing hundreds of off-screen glyphs.

Answer (score 0):

In a simpliest way you can just recreate your label every time. Do something like this.

```
String text = "text";

Lable createLabel(String addText) {
  text = text + addText
  return Label(text, skin)
}
```

Then just call this function where you need a label